# How to run a web "protocol" (specifically steam://) with Python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, steam

I was thinking of creating an app "organizer" with Python. This app would simply organize my apps and games.
I was thinking of opening Steam games *remotely*. Since Steam uses steam://rungameid/(e.g. 440 for Team Fortress 2), I thought of using this code to open a game:

```
import webbrowser
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open("steam://rungameid/440")
```

and it doesn't work, nor does it give an error. It merely shows the "Who's using Chrome?" portal and after you choose any account, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not force a specific browser, you want the default protocol handler:

```
import webbrowser  
webbrowser.open("steam://...")
```

internally this should end up calling `os.startfile` which should call `ShellExecute` on Windows which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!